# How to make a Docker container's service accessible via the container's IP address?

Tags: docker, port, ip-address

I'm a bit confused. Trying to run both a HTTP server listening on port 8080 and a SSH server listening on port 22 inside a Docker container I managed to accomplish the latter but strangely not the former.

Here is what I want to achieve and how I tried it:

I want to access services running inside a Docker container **using the IP address assigned to the container**:

```
ssh user@172.17.0.2
curl http://172.17.0.2:8080
```

**Note:** *I know this is not how you would configure a real web server but I want the container to mimic an embedded device which runs both services and which I don't have available all the time. (So it's really just a local non-production thing with no security requirements).*

I didn't expect integrating the SSH server to be easy, but to my surprise I just installed and started it and had to do nothing else to be able to connect to the machine via ssh (no `EXPOSE 22` or `--publish`).

Now I wanted to access the container via HTTP on port 8080 and fiddled with `--publish` and `EXPOSE` but only managed to make the HTTP server available through `localhost/127.0.0.1` on the host. So now I can access it via

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

but I want to access both services via the same IP address which is *NOT* `localhost` (e.g. the address the container got randomly assigned is totally OK for me).

Unfortunately

```
curl http://172.17.0.2:8080/
```

waits until it times out every time I tied it.

I tried `docker run` together with `-p 8080`, `-p 127.0.0.1:8080:8080`, `-p 172.17.0.2:8080:8080` and much more combinations, together or without `EXPOSE 8080` in the `Dockerfile` but without success.

Why can I access the container via port 22 without having exposed anything?

And how do I make it accessible via the container's IP address?

**Update:** looks like I'm experiencing exactly what's described [here](https://forums.docker.com/t/bind-cannot-assign-requested-address/12230).

Comment: Can you clarify if you your goal is to access the container with a specific IP address like `172.17.0.2` or through any IP address? Also, is the IP address `172.17.0.2` for a remote server or your local machine?

Comment: Usually you do none of these things – you don’t run an ssh daemon in a container (only the main process that’s running your HTTP server) and you never ever directly refer to a container’s private IP address.

Comment: `docker exec -it {container_id} bash`, where the `bash` what ever yr server runs

Comment: Maybe the problem is with the server itself (firewall, etc), can you run HTTP server without docker, and try to access it on `172.17.0.2:8080`?

Comment: you can use netcat to listen: `nc -l 172.17.0.2 8080`

Comment: I don't know what exactly you mean by 'server' since the container and curl are running on the same machine - but anyway you pointed me in the right direction: I've set `http_proxy` system wide so `curl` tried to connect via proxy..  D'ough - I hope this is due to the weather here in Germany....